# What run levels determine that the service will start on reboot?

Tags: linux, centos, runlevel

I understand what run levels means, what I am having trouble understanding is. How to determine which service will start on system reboot depending upon run levels?

```
 chkconfig httpd --list 
    chkconfig httpd         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Or if not, where can I check what services will start automatically on system reboot?

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command to list all services which are enabled at boot:

```
#chkconfig --list | grep $(runlevel | awk '{ print $2}'):on
```

Sample output:

```
acpid           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
anacron         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
atd             0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
auditd          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
cpuspeed        0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
crond           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
dkms_autoinstaller  0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
haldaemon       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
hidd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
irqbalance      0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
kudzu           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
lighttpd        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
lm_sensors      0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
lvm2-monitor    0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
mcstrans        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
mdmonitor       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
messagebus      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
microcode_ctl   0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
mysqld          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
named           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
netfs           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
ntpd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
pcscd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
psacct          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
readahead_early 0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
restorecond     0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rhnsd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rpcgssd         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rpcidmapd       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
sendmail        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
setroubleshoot  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
smartd          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
snmpd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
sshd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
stor_agent      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:on    6:off
syslog          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
sysstat         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:off   5:on    6:off
vmware          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:off   5:on    6:off
xfs             0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
xinetd          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
yum-updatesd    0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

The first column of above output is the name of a service which is currently enabled at boot. You need to review each service.

Each number is a run level, there is a key "on" or "off" that will dictate weather that service is on or off at that particular run level.

You could also check it by the run level symlinks with:

```
# for runlevel symlinks:
ls /etc/rc*.d/
```

This will dislplay the services run at each run level as well.